# List all devices bound to a driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Let's say I have drivers A and B in the Linux kernel space, with devices bound to them. I would like to export API in the driver A to B to provide list of devices bound to the driver A. Is it possible for a driver A to get to know about all devices currently being detected and bound to that driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply register functions with A when driver B loads and call same function whenever device list is required.
e.g

Driver A <<< register_func(func_ptr_list); export register_func
Driver B <<< Call register_func with function list.

Multiple driver talks to each other using similar function element.  for example Look at module_int for cxgb4 and cxgb4i

Comment: What if there's a many-to-many mapping. I mean there can be multiple A devices, so drive A has multiple data structures per each device. Can I store data about drive B instance globally in drive A, not in data structures related to each device?

Comment: I would not recommend that, rather a single interface with wrapper data structure which could hold the pointer to valid device. It is important in kernel that you keep layering model intact rather jumping on each other objects through global heck.

Answer (score 0):

### If your driver is pci driver, then:

```c
void get_all_devices_of_driver(const char *driver_name)
{
    bool found = false;

    struct pci_dev *pdev = NULL;
    for_each_pci_dev (pdev) {
        if (!strcmp(dev_driver_string(&pdev->dev),
                driver_name)) {
                // do what you want
        }
    }
}
```

#### Or use kernel's general helper function:

```c
/**
 * driver_for_each_device - Iterator for devices bound to a driver.
 * @drv: Driver we're iterating.
 * @start: Device to begin with
 * @data: Data to pass to the callback.
 * @fn: Function to call for each device.
 *
 * Iterate over the @drv's list of devices calling @fn for each one.
 */
int driver_for_each_device(struct device_driver *drv, struct device *start,
               void *data, int (*fn)(struct device *, void *))
{
    struct klist_iter i;
    struct device *dev;
    int error = 0;

    if (!drv)
        return -EINVAL;

    klist_iter_init_node(&drv->p->klist_devices, &i,
                 start ? &start->p->knode_driver : NULL);
    while (!error && (dev = next_device(&i)))
        error = fn(dev, data);
    klist_iter_exit(&i);
    return error;
}
```